# Oozie JAVA Action generated empty output files

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run a JAVA action in oozie. This JAVA action is supposed to write some files locally. By default the user running the JAVA action is yarn.
The output files are generated, but all of them are empty.

Comment: Is your logic generating any output? Can you share the java code and oozie java action arguments?

Comment: Apologies Nishu I can't share the code. But yes I can tell you if I run the JAVA standalone application the files are generated and they have the data in it. But when I run the same using oozie JAVA action, the files get created but there is no data in them.

Also, while running it as a standalone application, the permissions of the files generated is 664 and while running it via oozie the permissions of the files generated are 644.

The files created by standalone java application have user and group both as "cloudera" while running via oozie they both are "yarn".

Hope this clarifies more.

Comment: Share your oozie action, How are you writing files? using HDFSOutputstream or fileoutputstream?

Comment: Oozie uses a single Mapper MR job for running your java action. The MR can run on any node in the cluster. Instead of writing the data locally, you need to write them to the HDFS. [Sample](https://github.com/abhishekbafna/oozie-wf-example/blob/master/src/main/java/example/oozie/wf/java/DataGenerator.java).

Comment: Try to run on a single node cluster to confirm whether you are able to write the data to local file system. If it works, then you can isolate the issue as - it is not able to process and write the data in a multi node cluster. One of the reason could be, Oozie triggers a map/reduce job and jobs will be running in any of the nodes in the cluster and it is not able to process it. In my experience, its better to write it back to HDFS and add one more action in oozie to load the data from HDFS to Local File system.